# JavaFX - Check the position of a label based on a mouse click

Tags: javafx

I try to write a code that find the label on which one have clicked.

Using an event listener, I got the positions of the event using getX() and getY().

However, I cannot find the adequate methods for the label positions in order to compare them.

Below is my code, and its ouput.

```
public class Beta extends Application {

    final Label[] answerLabel = new Label[4];
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        final int numCols = 7 ;
        final int numRows = 12 ;
        
        //final Label[] answerLabel = new Label[4];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
            ColumnConstraints colConst = new ColumnConstraints();
            colConst.setPercentWidth(100.0 / numCols);
            root.getColumnConstraints().add(colConst);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            RowConstraints rowConst = new RowConstraints();
            rowConst.setPercentHeight(100.0 / numRows);
            root.getRowConstraints().add(rowConst);         
        }
                
        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
            answerLabel[i] = new Label();
            answerLabel[i].setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
            answerLabel[i].setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
            answerLabel[i].setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;-fx-font-size: 7pt;-fx-padding: 0;");
            answerLabel[i].setPadding(new Insets(10)); 
            answerLabel[i].setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
            root.add(answerLabel[i], 3, i +5, 1, 1);
            
            answerLabel[i].setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                    answerLabelPressed(e);
                }
            });
        }
        
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 900, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void answerLabelPressed(MouseEvent e)
    {

        int labelSelected;

        double px = e.getX();
        double py = e.getY();
        
        System.out.println("px = " + px + " py = " + py);
        
        for (labelSelected = 0; labelSelected < 4; labelSelected++)
        {
            
            System.out.println("answerLabel[labelSelected].getLayoutX() = " + answerLabel[labelSelected].getLayoutX());
            System.out.println("answerLabel[labelSelected].getLayoutY() = " + answerLabel[labelSelected].getLayoutY());
        }
    }   
   
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
px = 42.0 py = 7.0
answerLabel[labelSelected].getLayoutX() = 386.0
view.answerLabel[labelSelected].getLayoutY() = 208.0
answerLabel[labelSelected].getLayoutX() = 386.0 
view.answerLabel[labelSelected].getLayoutY() = 250.0  
answerLabel[labelSelected].getLayoutX() = 386.0 
view.answerLabel[labelSelected].getLayoutY() = 292.0 
answerLabel[labelSelected].getLayoutX() = 386.0 
view.answerLabel[labelSelected].getLayoutY() = 333.0
```

Upadate: The main purpose was to find/check the equivalent JavaFX methods of those used in Java Swing.
An alternative and better algorithm beeing as one can read in most popular Java books :

> ```
> MouseListener ml = new MouseListener() { 
>   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { 
>     report("mouseClicked", e.paramString()); 
>   }
> ```

In Java Swing, one should read :

```
    Point p = e.getComponent().getLocation();
    System.out.println("px = " + p.getX() + " py = " + p.getY());

    for (labelSelected = 0; labelSelected < 4; labelSelected++)
    {

        System.out.println("answerLabel[labelSelected].getX() = " + answerLabel[labelSelected].getX());
        System.out.println("answerLabel[labelSelected].getY() = " + answerLabel[labelSelected].getY());
    }
```

Comment: You already know which label was clicked: it's the one on which the event handler was registered.

Comment: I made an update of my request. To summarize, I would like to know equivalent method in JavaFX for answerLabel[labelSelected].getX() in Java Swing.

Comment: You already have the equivalent method in your code; it is `getLayoutX()`. That gives you the coordinates of the label in its parent's coordinate system.

Comment: Yes, but as you can see their values are not the same. px = 42.0 py = 7.0 answerLabel[labelSelected].getLayoutX() = 386.0 view.answerLabel[labelSelected].getLayoutY() = 208.0. Sometimes I use Java robots so these methods could be useful in this case.

Comment: Of course, because `px` and `py` are the coordinates of the mouse click *in the label's coordinate system*.

Comment: Then, "You already have the equivalent method in your code; it is getLayoutX()." is not correct. I will just suppose that this method doesn't work in JavaFX comparatively to Swing.

Comment: You asked for the equivalent of `JComponent.getX()`. The closest equivalent is `Node.getLayoutX()`. You keep changing what you're asking, so it's really impossible to answer.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm not talking about the "closest equivalent" but just the equivalent. By equivalent I mean the label method providing the SAME output. ie:  px = 42.0 py = 7.0 answerLabel[labelSelected].getX() = 42.0 view.answerLabel[labelSelected].getY() = 7.0. As previously stated above this is possible in Java Swing.

Comment: But `px` and `py` have nothing to do with what you are currently asking about. Those are coordinates of the mouse click. You asked for the equivalent of the coordinates of the label. If you can't be clear about what you are asking, it's not possible to answer you.

Comment: *"As previously stated above this is possible in Java Swing."*. This is clearly nonsense. Unless the user happened to click on the exact top left of the label, there is no possible sense in which the coordinates of the mouse click would be equal to the coordinates of the label.

Comment: In Swing the same code with getX/getY for both the mouse click and the label returns : px = 42.0 py = 7.0 answerLabel[labelSelected].getX() = 42.0 view.answerLabel[labelSelected].getY() = 7.0. My CONCLUSION is that in JavaFX  there is  NO equivalent ,reason it's called getLayoutX.

Comment: *"In Swing the same code with getX/getY for both the mouse click and the label returns ..."*. Sorry: I don't believe you. You're talking nonsense. And as already explained, there is no reason to want to compare the coordinates of a label with the coordinates of a mouse click anyway.

Comment: "You're talking nonsense. And as already explained, there is no reason to want to compare the coordinates of a label with the coordinates of a mouse click anyway." Then the compiler for Java Swing is "talking nonsense"...I confirm again, the code above works fine in Swing using :       Point p = e.getComponent().getLocation(); px=p.getX(); py=p.getY(); ie: px returns the same value than answerLabel[labelSelected].getX() and py returns the same value than answerLabel[labelSelected].getY().

Comment: But that's not the same thing you do in your JAvaFX code. Of course those give the same coordinates, because `e.getComponent()` gives you a reference to the label on which the user clicked: i.e. if `answerLabel[labelSelected]` is the label on which the user clicked, then `answerLabel[selectedLabel]` *is the exact same object as* `e.getComponent()`.

Comment: The equivalent in JavaFX would be something like `((Node)e.getTarget()).getLayoutX()`, which would give you the same as `label.getLayoutX()`, but it would only be the same because `e.getTarget()` is the exact same object as the label. There is no point in comparing the coordinates of the exact same object in either toolkit.

Comment: You seem to have been unfortunate enough to come across some really badly written Swing code, in which you're placing too much trust. First: you should understand what the code is doing; each method call individually. I don't think you understand what `e.getComponent()` is doing, for example, and why `e.getComponent().getLocation().getX()` (which of course is the same as `e.getComponent().getX()`) is the same as `label.getX()`. Second, you should critically evaluate code (even code in a book) before using it. Learn to use the API docs as your primary reference.

Comment: You supposed that I trusted the code but instead, while at the first instance, I try to re-implement it in JavaFX as exercise. As you can see I equally have years in programming...However, your explanation "((Node)e.getTarget()).getLayoutX(), which would give you the same as label.getLayoutX()," give me better information. So, as conclusion, in regard to a control, in JavaFX : ((Node)e.getTarget()) is the equivalent in Java Swing of  e.getComponent().getLocation().

Comment: *" `((Node)e.getTarget())` is the equivalent in Java Swing of `e.getComponent().getLocation()` "*. No, obviously those are not equivalent. One gives you a UI component, and one gives you a point. How can they be equivalent, in any sense?

Comment: This time, by equivalence, I use your own definition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to manually compute which node the mouse clicked on. That calculation is already done for you by the framework. That's how the framework knows which event handlers to invoke. If you simply add a unique handler to each node, then when that handler is invoked only that node could be the source. This is demonstrated in [@James_D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73376345/6395627).

However, if you want to manually compute which node was clicked (e.g., for fun or just for learning purposes), then here is a runnable example:

```java
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var labels = IntStream.range(0, 12)
        .mapToObj(this::createLabel)
        .toArray(Label[]::new);

    var grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(20));
    grid.setHgap(20);
    grid.setVgap(20);
    grid.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
      var clickedOnLabel = getClickedOnLabel(labels, e);
      if (clickedOnLabel == null) {
        System.out.println("You did not click on a label!");
      } else {
        System.out.printf("You clicked on a label: '%s'%n", clickedOnLabel.getText());
      }
    });

    int i = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
      for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        grid.add(labels[i++], col, row);
      }
    }

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(grid));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private Label getClickedOnLabel(Label[] labels, MouseEvent event) {
    for (var label : labels) {
      var bounds = label.localToScene(label.getBoundsInLocal());
      if (bounds.contains(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY())) {
        return label;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  private Label createLabel(int n) {
    var label = new Label(String.format("Label #%02d", n));
    label.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
    label.setPadding(new Insets(5));
    label.setFont(Font.font("Monospaced", 15.0));
    label.setBorder(Border.stroke(Color.BLACK));
    return label;
  }
}
```

The important part, the part which computes which label was clicked on, is here:

```java
private Label getClickedOnLabel(Label[] labels, MouseEvent event) {
  for (var label : labels) {
    var bounds = label.localToScene(label.getBoundsInLocal());
    if (bounds.contains(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY())) {
      return label;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

It gets the bounds of each `Label` in the scene's coordinate space, and then tests if the mouse's location—also in the scene's coordinate space—is contained within those bounds. You can use whatever coordinate space you like (e.g., the screen's, the grid pane's, the label's, etc.), as long as you use the same one for both the label's bounds and the mouse's location. Note the mouse's local coordinates (i.e., `getX()` and `getY()`) are in the *source node's* coordinate space. The source node is the node that the currently-being-invoked handler was registered with for the specific event currently being processed (the `GridPane` in the above example).

**But again, for any "real" code, I strongly recommend you use the solution in @James_D's answer.**

Answer (score 2):

> I try to write a code that find the label on which one have clicked.

You create four labels, and you create a listener for each label. Each listener is only registered with one label.

So there is no need to get your hands dirty with the coordinates of the click (the event handling mechanism has already done all of that for you, when it decided to which node to dispatch the event). Just reference the label that was clicked:

```
public class Beta extends Application {

    final Label[] answerLabel = new Label[4];
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        final int numCols = 7 ;
        final int numRows = 12 ;
                    
        for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
            ColumnConstraints colConst = new ColumnConstraints();
            colConst.setPercentWidth(100.0 / numCols);
            root.getColumnConstraints().add(colConst);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            RowConstraints rowConst = new RowConstraints();
            rowConst.setPercentHeight(100.0 / numRows);
            root.getRowConstraints().add(rowConst);         
        }
                
        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
            answerLabel[i] = new Label();
            answerLabel[i].setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
            answerLabel[i].setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
            answerLabel[i].setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;-fx-font-size: 7pt;-fx-padding: 0;");
            answerLabel[i].setPadding(new Insets(10)); 
            answerLabel[i].setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
            root.add(answerLabel[i], 3, i +5, 1, 1);

            Label currentLabel = answerLabel[i];
            int currentIndex = i ;
            
            answerLabel[i].setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                System.out.println("Clicked on label "+currentIndex);

                // just for demo: in real life use external stylesheets
                // and pseudoclasses, etc.
                for (Label label : answerLabel) {
                    label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;-fx-font-size: 7pt;-fx-padding: 0;");
                }
                currentLabel.setStyle("-fx-background-color: gold;-fx-font-size: 7pt;-fx-padding: 0;");
            });
        }
        
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 900, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: In swing this way/algorithm was working. Obviously your above code is easier but according to the context it may  requieres further lines of codes.

Comment: @Space But in Swing, you would do the same as in my answer. You wouldn't iterate over all the labels and test which intersected the mouse click. (At least, I hope you wouldn't write Swing code like that.)

Comment: Unfortunately,the algorithm (about a thousand of lines) in the book was exactly like I wrote it. I just try to convert it into javafx at the same time to read the full code. Your code above is obviously better.

Comment: I can give you the name of the book if you want...

Comment: @Space A _book_ told you to manually test for which component/node the mouse was hovering over when clicked? I suppose I could understand that if they were trying to teach some sort of concept to you, but both Swing and JavaFX (and pretty much every UI framework out there) already does this calculation for you—that's how the framework knows which listeners/handlers to invoke. Any "real" code would use the approach demonstrated in this answer.

Comment: @Slaw I am sure you can read. " I just try to convert it into javafx at the same time to read the full code. Your code above is obviously better. " I've not said I was trying to optimise a code.

Comment: @Space I read that. It doesn't really change my comment, as my comment—in response to "_I can give you the name of the book if you want..._"—is mostly conveying my shock that a published book would tell you to do otherwise.

Comment: @Slaw  "I can give you the name of the book if you want..."   By "you" I means James_D... Have a good coding...

Comment: @Space I... don't understand what you're trying to say. Yes, your original comment is to James_D. That doesn't matter. This is a public forum, and I was joining the conversation.

Comment: @Space I would love to know which book recommends that approach. For obvious reasons, it is a terrible way to solve this problem.

Comment: @James_D " I would love to know which book recommends that approach. For obvious reasons, it is a terrible way to solve this problem". I agree, there are a lot bad algorithm in the code. I will put the name of the book below but will delete it later.

Comment: I see no reason to delete the comment. If it really says to do what you say it does (I haven't checked yet), it deserves public criticism.

Comment: I'm just scanning through it (admittedly the 7th edition, which is old). It is not a good book; it is full of really bad practices and very bizarre coding styles. (Every single example has a threading error, for example.) I would not trust anything in it.

Comment: @James_D I resolved most of the bugs at that time but didn't try to optimise the codes.

Comment: @Space I think you're missing the point. It's not about "bugs". The book is unmitigated garbage. Reading it and replicating the coding style will make you a bad programmer. If you have a copy, throw it out.

Comment: @James_D It was not my main Java Swing book. Anyway, I'm now trying to focuse on JavaFX.